# SQL query which puts columns from rows into one row

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables:

- ***Customer***(cust_id, cust_name)
- ***Refund*** (ref_id, cust_id, ref_date, ref_amount)

*cust_id* is the foreign key which points out to a **Customer**.

Each **Customer** can have several refunds. I want to get a list of customers and only two dates of refunds for each cutomer. Each customer and dates of his refunds **must be in one row**. I.e. I want to get the foolowing result:

(cust_name, ref_date1, ref_amount1, ref_date2, ref_amount2)

For example - *'John Smith', '06/06/2012', 500.0,  '08/05/2014', 345.5*

How can I get this?
Thanx!

(If it is important I use Oracle 11g)

Comment: What query have you tried? Please post that!!

Comment: If a customer has 10 refunds. Which 2 do you want the dates and amounts for?

Comment: Update your question with the attempt you've made. Also, **why** do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gets the two most recent refunds:

```
select c.cust_name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then ref_date end) as ref_date1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then ref_amount end) as ref_amount1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then ref_date end) as ref_date2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then ref_amount end) as ref_amount2
from customer c join
     (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cust_id order by ref_date desc) as seqnum 
      from refund r
     ) r
     on c.cust_id = r.cust_id
where seqnum <= 2
group by c.cust_name;
```

Comment: Wow! This is what I need. The query works perfectly. Thanx a lot  Gordon!